# Rotate GameObject To Look Down

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have a simple Unity3d script that is supposed to move a GameObject to a certain point and look down on that point from above.

My script is partially working; the GameObject is moving to the correct point but its not looking down from above. So the rotation is wrong. The GameObject flips upside down.

Can you help me get my GameObject to look straight down?

```
public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3     targetPosition          = new Vector3(5, 10, 5);
    private Quaternion  targetRotation          = new Quaternion(90, 0, 0, 0);
    private float       speed                   = 6f;

    void LateUpdate () {

        transform.position  = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        transform.rotation  = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quaternion.Slerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) takes a "starting rotation" as the 1st parameter. In your code, `transform.rotation` is updated every time `LateUpdate()` is executed.

You may have your original rotation (before applying any rotation) saved as a variable `originalRtn`, and update the rotation by `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(originRtn, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);`.